What does it mean to be 'gathered to the name of the Lord Jesus alone'?
I received a letter from someone in the UK which, twice, used this expression and I wonder what it was meant to convey, especially the word 'alone'.
Is this a saying of a particular group of self-identifying Christians ?
If so, what are they communicating by the 'alone' ?
Are they implying that no other matters can be included as a ground of gathering ?
And why is the title 'Christ' not mentioned, or 'Son of God' ?

I found the phrase in question in this link, the front-page of a particular group giving further links to John Nelson Darby. I will have to look into this. It may also be that other denominations use that phrase about believers being 'gathered to the name of the Lord Jesus alone.' But this group certainly does. http://www.mcclean.me.uk/mse/jnd/jnd.htm

Isn't "Alone" in this context just a reference to "No other gods" as in "Christ Alone" = "Only Christ"?

@Wyrsa Not necessarily. Some who associate with the JN Darby movement disagree with him in his biblical stance that the Son was the eternal Son. They seem to be the Plymouth Brethren who refuse to speak of 'the Son' prior to the incarnation of the Word. But they do speak of 'the Lord Jesus' and - if gathered 'alone' to that name, that might be a clue that they reject the Eternal Sonship of the Son. I don't know yet, but need to investigate why such emphasis on 'the name of the Lord Jesus alone'.

As there is no Bible verse that uses that expression why not ask him what he means?

Picking up from the link posted in comments to the OP, John Nelson Darby reputedly “gathered with others to the name of the Lord Jesus Christ alone”:

In 1827, deploring the evils and divisions in Christendom, and discovering from God's Word the blessed and practical truth that "there is One Body", and that every true believer on earth is a member thereof, and further, that Scripture recognises no other membership, he severed his connection with the National Church, and gathered with others to the name of the Lord Jesus Christ alone (Matthew 18: 20).

Matthew 18:20 says this, in both the KJV and the Scofield Bible:

For where two or three are gathered together in my name, there I am in the midst of them. (KJV and Scofield Bible)

The expression “to the name of the Lord Jesus Christ alone” seems to have originated with John Nelson Darby.
The Plymouth Brethren Christian Church was created by John Nelson Darby.  The following quotes are taken from their official web site

The Plymouth Brethren Christian Church is over 180 years old, and was created by the influential Protestant thinker, John Nelson Darby.  We believe the term ‘Exclusive Brethren’ was coined by commentators outside of the Church some decades ago. The correct name for our Community, and the one we prefer, is the Plymouth Brethren Christian Church.  The majority of our members are born into our Church. However, there are exceptions of some joining from the wider community that are prepared to commit that are is prepared to commit to our beliefs and way of life.

Their fellowship, which is central to their faith, is expressed by only eating and drinking with those with whom they celebrate the Lord’s Supper.  This is known as the doctrine of separation as described here

Members of the Plymouth Brethren Christian Church (PBCC) make a commitment to only eat and drink with those with whom we celebrate the Lord’s Supper. We celebrate the Lord’s Supper every Sunday in small groups. This solemn and sacred occasion of fellowship together is a commitment to one another to seek to live a life of purity, in line with scripture.  The doctrine of separation does not mean we isolate ourselves from the world. Instead, it encourages us to move closer to God, by distancing ourselves from the beliefs and practices that are contrary to biblical principles – the Lord’s Supper being central to our beliefs.

Various independent branches of the Plymouth Brethren have fellowship only with those who have been invited to partake of the bread and wine every Sunday.  Christians might recognise this practice as “closed communion”.
The independent, or Open Brethren separated from the Exclusive Brethren and the Plymouth assembly.  The Open Brethren also follow the practice of restricting those who can have fellowship with them or participate in communion. This extract explains

Nonbelievers are not to partake of the "Breaking of Bread", though this proves generally difficult to enforce in larger assemblies. Regardless, regular attendance for believers is felt to be an act of obedience to the New Testament command that they should not neglect the assembling of themselves together.  Despite the Brethren's rejection of the term 'member', many observers use the term to refer to those who attend meetings. Visiting brethren have traditionally been expected to bring a "letter of commendation" from their "home assembly", assuring the group they are visiting that they are in fellowship and not under any form of discipline. This practice is somewhat less common today than in years past, however.

Many assemblies operate a "back seat" or "guest row" during the Breaking of Bread so that neither the offering bag nor the emblems of bread and wine will pass down the row of those not in fellowship.  More information here

Because some assemblies do not encourage strangers to take Communion, it is common for those who are travelling to take with them a "letter of introduction" so they might be permitted to take Communion away from their home assemblies. These letters are typically read aloud to those present at the "Remembrance Meeting" and serve the purpose of introducing visitors to the meetings so that they can be made welcome and benefit from fellowship. These Open Brethren meetings operate what is termed a "Closed Table Policy". Any stranger arriving at such a meeting without a letter is allowed only to observe the meeting.

Finally, a division arose in 1861 between the Gospel Standard Strict Baptists and the early Plymouth Brethren.  John Nelson Darby held to the doctrine of the eternal sonship of the Son of God. One such group who broke away were the Taylor Brethren who do not believe in the eternal sonship of the Son of God.  John Nelson Darby abhorred that view, writing “There are persons who take it that Christ was only Son as come into the world. I lose all that the Son is – if he is only son as incarnate.”
What does it mean to be 'gathered to the name of the Lord Jesus alone'?  Within some Brethren communities, it might indicate a rejection of the doctrine of Jesus as the eternal Son of God.  Cleaving together of such like-minded believers distinguishes them from those Brethren communities that agree with John Nelson Darby.
Is this a saying of a particular group of self-identifying Christians?  John Nelson Darby used the exact phrase “the name of the Lord Jesus Christ alone”.  There is, however, disagreement within some of the breakaway groups as to the eternal sonship of the Lord Jesus Christ. One such group is the Taylor Brethren. (N.B. please see comment by OP regarding this)
If so, what are they communicating by the ‘alone’?  From what I’ve read, it seems that the expression “the Lord Jesus alone” refers to those Brethren who deny the eternal sonship of Christ Jesus, who believe that Jesus only became the Son at his incarnation.
Are they implying that no other matters can be included as a ground of gathering?  It seems that only those who subscribe to the teachings of that group and who are formally welcomed into their fellowship can be included fully.
And why is the title 'Christ' not mentioned, or 'Son of God'?  I can only assume that whereas John Nelson Darby subscribed to the eternal sonship of “the Lord Jesus Christ”, and used that very expression, there are other divisions within Brethren fellowships who disagree, and that may explain why they say only “the Lord Jesus”.

Both the early 'Plymouth' Brethren and the early 'Strict Baptists' faced the error that states that Jesus Christ is 'Son' only by incarnation and not Son of the Father eternally. The 'Gospel Standard Strict Baptists' are they who broke away and held eternal Sonship. I have up-voted (an accepted) but I think your wording is misleading in this regard. The 'Taylor' Brethren are they who maintained the Taylor error ('son' only by incarnation) but there are latter day 'Taylor' Brethren who now call themselves 'Plymouth' Brethren thereby obscuring their doctrine.

Thank you for the clarification that latter day Taylor Brethren now call themselves Plymouth Brethren. Unless a person belongs to the fellowship, it's very difficult to ascertain exactly what they do believe.

Yes, the wording Finally, a division arose in 1861 between the Gospel Standard Strict Baptists and the early Plymouth Brethren. John Nelson Darby held to the doctrine of the eternal sonship of the Son of God makes it sound as though the Gospel Standard Strict Baptists disagreed with JND on the matter of eternal Sonship. Which is not the case. They were the division of Baptists who separated from others in order to be faithful to the truth of eternal Sonship.
